# Отправить данные с формы + аттачмент

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Нужна помощь, в jQuery я скорее -1, чем даже 0. Только начинаю. Проблема такая - на сайте есть кнопка "Заказать", при нажатии на которую открывается форма для заполнения контактной информации, после заполнения клик на кнопку "Ок" и данные с формы + аттачмент с сайта должен уходить мне на почту в виде письма. Так вот аттачмент отправить удалось, а данные с формы он не забирает. Что исправить?

JS:

```
$btnConfirm.on('click', () => {

    var imageName = imageEditor.getImageName();
    var dataURL = imageEditor.toDataURL();
    var blob, type, w;

    blob = base64ToBlob(dataURL);
    type = blob.type.split('/')[1];
    if (imageName.split('.').pop() !== type) {
        imageName += '.' + type;
    }

    let d = new FormData(my_form);
    d.append('file', blob, imageName);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/veido_pats/post.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: d,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#my_form').hide('slow');
            $('#my_message').html(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP  Обработчик:

```
<?php 

$email = trim($_POST['email']); 
$client_name = trim($_POST['client_name']); 
$surname = trim($_POST['surname']); 
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']); 

move_uploaded_file( 
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],  
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].".png" 
);  

$to = 'dinvite@dinvite.lv';  

// Email subject  
$subject = 'Veido-pats pasūtījums';   

// Attachment file  
$file = $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].".png";  

// Email body content  

$message = "<b>Vārds:</b> $client_name \r\n<b>Uzvārds:</b>  $surname \r\n<b>E-pasts:</b>  $email \r\n<b>Telefona nr.:</b>  $phone\r\n";

// Header for sender info  
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n"; // от кого
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

//$headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";  
//$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

// Boundary   
$semi_rand = md5(time());   
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";   

// Headers for attachment   
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";  

// Multipart boundary   
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .  
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";   

// Preparing attachment  
if(!empty($file) > 0){  
    if(is_file($file)){  
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";  
        $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb");  
        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file));  

        @fclose($fp);  
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .   
        "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" .  
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .   
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";  
    }  
}  
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";  
$returnpath = "-f" . $from;  

// Send email  
$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);   

echo $mail.'Paldies! Pasūtījums saņemts! Ar Jums sazināsies tuvākajā laikā!' 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

При условии, что форма `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Аттачментом является изображение с встроенного визуального редактора.. его прикреплять не нужно пользователю..он уходит на почту, но с собой данные с формы не забирает